# It is automatically buffered

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, buffer

Currently, they were starting a project using a `create-react-app`, developing `react.js` and `node.js`, creating servers at high speed, checking view connections with servers, and working on DB connections. The educational example project separated the frontend folder and the backend folder separately but wanted to distribute it directly to the server after the project was completed. So I decided to take charge of both frontend and backend in one folder. The educational example project separated the front end folder and the backend folder separately, but I wanted to distribute it directly to the server after the project was completed, so I decided to take charge of both the front end and the backend in one folder, but there was an unexpected problem. The DB connection succeeded, but when I checked the value by selecting the value, it was automatically buffered. I have tried many methods such as toString(), JSON.parse, stringify, etc., but these methods decode the value already buffered on DB and server. I want to get what I’ve been doing in the DB from the start.
For reference, the database is using a MariaDB

[image]

Comment: Could you share more details as to what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: I compared it with the Korean hosting company 'cafe24' and Amazon 'AWS'. AWS was normally output without separate buffer processing, but 'cafe24' was automatically encoded and output; so I put my inquiries into cafe24.I’ll let you know after I get the answer. thk :)